# How do I set FBReader as the default mobi ebook reader?

Tags: nautilus, xdg

Is there a quick simple way of installing FBReader? Also, how do I fix the filetype not being recognized (mime TYPES?)

I want to set FB Reader as the default Open for mobi ebooks, but it's not recognized

Answer (score 2):

Install FBReader:

`sudo apt-get install fbreader`

Associate with .mobi format:

`xdg-mime default /usr/share/applications/FBReader.desktop application/x-mobipocket-ebook`