# Xubuntu: How to make fBreader the default ebook reader?

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, xfce, ebooks, mobi

How do I set fBreader (already installed with `sudo apt-get install fbreader`) to be the default epub and mobi file reader in Xubuntu 18.04? When I double click a .mobi or .epub file, fbReader does not open, and instead I am asked what kind of a file it is.

[How do I set FBReader as the default mobi ebook reader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98112/how-do-i-set-fbreader-as-the-default-mobi-ebook-reader) is specific to non-Xubuntu flavors and does not work with Xubuntu. Unable to find another relevant suggestion relevant to Xubuntu.

Comment: What error message do you receive when you try the linked solution? Why do you believe it does not work with XUbuntu?

Comment: Always [edit] additional info into your question as comments can be deleted for numerous reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Xubuntu 18.04, you should have a "MIME type editor" application.

Open it, filter by mobi. One line should remain. You can edit the default application on the right:
[image: change for mobi]

Then repeat same operation for epub:
[image]

Then close the MIME type editor. From now, opening an epub or mobi file will be done using FBReader.